# How to display flags in Visual Studio Registers panel?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, visual-studio-debugging, eflags

I noticed some other people's Registers panel in Visual Studio shows the flags.

[image]

(Source: https://youtu.be/LqyVybUodXE?t=163)

However, my Registers pane looks like this:

[image]

There is no flags info in the panel. I checked around the settings and options and can't find any clue. How to display them in the Registers panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just after I posted the question, I found right-clicking in the panel gives you options to show different data.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the debug menu then go on registers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).